# how to store upto 1,000,000,000 elements

Tags: c, arrays, size

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int max_b(int,int);
int max(int[],int);

int main(){

    int num_tests;
    scanf("%d",&num_tests);
    int array_n[num_tests];
    int array_b[num_tests];
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<num_tests;i++){
        scanf("%d %d",&array_n[i],&array_b[i]);
    }
    for (j=0;j<num_tests;j++){
        int A = 1;
        int N = array_n[j];
        int B = array_b[j];
        int max_num_b;
        max_num_b = max_b(N,B);
        int array2[max_num_b];
        int k;
        for (k=0;k<max_num_b;k++){
            int num_a,num_b;
            num_a = N-(k+1)*B;
            num_b = k+1;
            array2[k] = num_a*num_b;            
        }
        printf("%d\n",max(array2,max_num_b));
    }

}

int max(int array[],int a){
    int max_num = 0,i;
    for (i=0;i<a;i++){
        if (array[i] > max_num){
            max_num = array[i];
        }
    }
    return max_num;
}

int max_b(int n,int b){
    return n/b;
}
```

my first input is num of test cases T (say 1),and second input is 1,000,000,000 1 . So then the code tries to form an array of 10^9 size and the program ends up showing segmentation fault. However the code runs well upto 1,000,000 1. how can I store upto 10^9 elements. If its not possible then how can I store so many numbers.
Should I use malloc, if yes then how. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A dirty hack for "throwaway" programs is to use `static int array_n[num_tests];` &c.

Comment: assuming your platform has 32bit `int`, this will be nearly 4GiB of data. Most implementations use the stack for variables with *automatic storage duration* (here: local variables), which will never be able to hold **this** amount. Yes, using `malloc()` **could** work.

Comment: @bathsheba would i be able to allocate that much memory using static int array

Comment: btw, you don't really want to *type in* a billion values?

Comment: @FelixPalmen how should i use malloc, can i use it to increase array size

Comment: Possibly. But I think you should regard such an approach as non-portable.

Comment: You have two arrays of the same size, both would need a little less than 4GiB for a billion elements. This won't fit in the address space of `x86`, but it should work with `static` arrays on e.g. `x86_64`, given you have enough physical RAM in your machine.

Comment: @FelixPalmen would i be able to use linked list given i have about 4GB RAM

Comment: One more thing to point out, since that huge number is being stored in `int num_tests` in prior and then you use it to define the size of your array, I guess you should use `long` since the size of these primitive data-types depend upon your machine. So, just to make sure that you don't miss the rest of the input.

Comment: @RamSharma uhm, no? With a linked list, you have an *extra* pointer for each element, consuming typically 4 or 8 bytes. This just makes it worse.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like your program doesn't need to create `array2[]` at all. Instead of filling this array and then searching for the maximum value inside it, just update `max_num` on the fly. in fact, it looks like the same applies to `array_n[]` and `array_b[]`. Do you *really* need to store these values?

Comment: @FelixPalmen ;( then in what way should i use malloc, could you write a line of code for that

Comment: Under linux&co your code should work unmodified after issuing `ulimit -s unlimited` (provided you have a 64-bit system and enough memory, of course)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to store this data at all. Just process it on the fly.

As far as I can tell, the following code produces the same results as the code you posted, but uses no arrays whatsoever.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int k, t, N, B, max, num_tests;
    scanf("%d", &num_tests);
    while (num_tests--) {
        scanf("%d %d", &N, &B);
        for (k=N/B,max=0; k>0; k--) {
            t = (N-k*B) * k;
            if (t > max) max = t;
        }
        printf("%d\n", max);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your logic isn't wrong, then I think this is a more viable approach. +1

Comment: @ManjinderSinghHanjra Just tested the two programs with a hundred random inputs. The outputs are identical. There's probably a faster way of finding the maximum value of `(N-k*B) * k`, but I think that belongs in another question.

Comment: for the sake of the range of the value being inserted in `num_tests` it should be a `long` or `unsigned long`, otherwise it would be a problem in while loop, and not all input will be consumed.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage yes, you are right, there is a problem though the code seems to  take a little more than one second but the constraint is to execute within one second, how can we increase the speed of this sort of code without using multithreads (I don't know how to use them)

Comment: @RamSharma As I suggested above, there are faster ways of finding the maximum value of `(N-k*B) * k`.  You don't need to test every value of k. This is a quadratic expression, so it only has a single peak, probably somewhere in the region of `N / (2*B)`.

Answer (score 1):

For a billion `int`s in two arrays, you will need nearly 8GiB of storage, assuming you have 32bit `int`s.

This is a really huge amount of memory and your best bet with standard C function is to request them via `malloc()` -- if your address space is large enough (on `i386`, it would be too small, but on `amd64` it should be fine) **and** if the system can provide that much memory, the following should work:

```
int main(){

    unsigned long num_tests;
    scanf("%lu",&num_tests);

    int *array_n = malloc((size_t)num_tests * sizeof(*array));
    if (!array_n)
    {
        fputs("couldn't allocate array_n\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    int *array_b = malloc((size_t)num_tests * sizeof(*array));
    if (!array_b)
    {
        fputs("couldn't allocate array_b\n", stderr);
        free(array_n);
        return 1;
    }

    size_t i,j;
    for (i=0;i<num_tests;i++){
        scanf("%d %d",&array_n[i],&array_b[i]);
    }

    // rest of code

    free(array_b);
    free(array_n);
}
```

Note I changed the `scanf()` to read an `unsigned long`, just to be sure. It's still not bullet-proof, though.

Answer (score 0):

You should **NOT** use variable length array declarations when the size is determined at runtime.

I would suggest you use `malloc()` instead. Replace the following lines

```
int num_tests;
scanf("%d",&num_tests);
int array_n[num_tests];
int array_b[num_tests];
```

With

```
int num_tests, *array_n, *array_b;

scanf("%d", &num_tests);

array_n = malloc(num_tests * sizeof(int));
if (array_n == NULL)
{
    printf("Memory allocation error for array_n!\n");
    return -1;
}

array_b = malloc(num_tests * sizeof(int));
if (array_b == NULL)
{
    /* cleanup */
    free(array_n);

    printf("Memory allocation error for array_b!\n");
    return -1;
}
```

As other comments pointed out, 1,000,000,000 elements need roughly 4GB of memory (double that as you have two arrays). So, you may run out of memory allocating this many integers.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, when you initialize an array the size must be constant. So use `#define NUM_TESTS 1000000000` instead.
Second, since an integers size is 4 bytes 10^9 integers would need 4 000 000 000 B which equals 4 GB. And its pretty 'hard' to 4 GB on the stack. You should use files or, if all your values are smaller than, lets say 256, you can use `char`s instead. Its still 1 GB, but thats way 'easier' to get.

Comment: "the size must be constant" - only in old-fashioned languages like C++.

Comment: @Bathsheba well, as C11 made VLAs an optional feature, it might be a good idea to avoid them ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Oops.

Comment: As for this answer, it should be improved. I think an **answer** should provide a bit more than just "general ideas".

Comment: @Bathsheba still you're correct, "*must be constant*" is wrong. It depends on the features the compiler supports.

Comment: @FelixPalmen What i meant is that it can't be a variable like an `int` for example.

Comment: @chrissidtmeier it can, read about [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#Examples) .. they're mandatory in C99 and an optional feature in C11.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Oh thanks, didn't know that. I only worked with .NET