# increase speed efficiency of the code

Tags: c, performance, optimization

```
// author- squeamishossifrage
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int k, t, A, N, B, max, num_tests;
    scanf("%d", &num_tests);
    while (num_tests--) {
        scanf("%d %d", &N, &B);
        A = 1;
        k = N / B;
        for (k=N/B,max=0; k>0; k--) {
            t = (N-k*B) * k;
            if (t > max) max = t;
        }
        printf("%d\n", max);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code (take from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45078669/253056)) seems to take a little more than one second but the constraint is to execute within one second. How can we increase the speed of this sort of code without using multithreads (I don't know how to use them) ?

Comment: Not that this will help, but why `k = N / B;`, and then `for (k=N/B,...`?

Comment: Most likely you need a more efficient *algorithm*. (It doesn't matter how much code optimisation you do if you start off with an inefficient algorithm - the code will still be slow.)

Comment: @PaulR can you suggest another algorithm for this

Comment: Would be more easy if you tell us what the algorithm should do?

Comment: This should probably be asked on Code Review, not SO.

Comment: @RamSharma: if you explain what the code is supposed to do then someone may be able to suggest a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Smells like a Project Euler challenge.

Comment: You could remove the redundant line `k = N / B;`

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yes he should do that but I think that is not the problem as the compiler should optimize that away. Also the variable `A` is unused but assigned: `A = 1;`. But I think the compiler should also optimize that.

Comment: Does not `t` mathematically is always `0`?

Comment: @paulR, the original question is - "Initially, each screen shows the number zero. Pressing the first button increments the number on the first screen by 1, and each click of the first button consumes 1 unit of energy.Pressing the second button increases the number on the second screen by the number which is currently appearing on the first screen. Each click of the second button consumes B units of energy.Initially the calculator has N units of energy. what is the max num on second calculator" here N and B are taken as inputs fromuser

Comment: @dlmeetei: No due integer division: Consider the followng: `k = N / B = 5 / 2 = 2` because of integer division. Now: `t = (N - k * B) = 5 - 2 * 2 = 1 != 0`.

Comment: A quick analysis shows that `t` might increase during the loop to a maximum and then decrease. If that is always so (you can check) then `break;` out of the loop when `t <= prevt` (store the previous value).

Comment: @AndreKampling, You are right. I was working out with a pen and paper.

Comment: The problem can be solved algebraically, `f(N,B) = N^2/(4*B)`. The only problem left is to round it to the correct step (not necessarily to the next integer, the steps are more coarse)

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding and flexability: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int k, N, B, max, num_tests;
    scanf("%d", &num_tests);
    while (num_tests--) {
        scanf("%d %d", &N, &B);
        k = (double)N / (2*B)+0.5;
        max = (N-k*B)*k;
        printf("%d\n", max);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Should be way more efficient without a loop. The concept is to solve the problem algebraically and then round appropriately.

The maximum k of

```
t = N*k - k²*B
```

can be found by differentiating to k:

```
k = N/(2*B)
```

This has to be rounded appropriately and then be inserted into the original equation

```
t = (N-k*B) * k;
```

which is the correct (maximum) solution then.

Answer (score 0):

the function: `printf()` and the function: `scanf()` are very 'heavy duty' and take many CPU cycles.

strongly suggest using `getchar_unlocked()` and `putchar_unlocked()` as they are MUCH faster.

here are two functions for I/O that are MUCH faster than `printf()` and `scanf()`  note the usage of `size_t` rather than `int`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fastRead( size_t *a );
void fastWrite( size_t a );

inline void fastRead(size_t *a)
{
    int c=0;
    // note: 32 is space character
    while (c<33) c=getchar_unlocked();

    // initialize result value
    *a=0;

    // punctuation parens, etc are show stoppers
    while (c>47 && c<58)
    {
        *a = (*a)*10 + (size_t)(c-48);
        c=getchar_unlocked();
    }
    //printf( "%s, value: %lu\n", __func__, *a );
} // end function: fastRead


inline void fastWrite(size_t a)
{
    char snum[20];
    //printf( "%s, %lu\n", __func__, a );

    int i=0;
    do
    {
        // 48 is numeric character 0
        snum[i++] = (char)((a%10)+(size_t)48);
        a=a/10;
    }while(a>0);

    i=i-1; // correction for overincrement from prior 'while' loop

    while(i>=0)
    {
        putchar_unlocked(snum[i--]);
    }
    putchar_unlocked('\n');
} // end function: fastWrite
```